# GetQueuedCompletionStatus - How to read clients messages without any socket struct

Tags: c, windows, winsock2, iocp

I'm trying to learn IOCP with C in Windows. The idea is to have a non-blocking server with threads that handle client messages.

I understand by now how to accept clients, etc.

But I still don't understand how to read each client's messages from `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` and print them.

I see online that all people pass a struct to reference it with `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` using the `LPOVERLAPPED` parameter, but how to do it without any struct?

Can someone tell me if that is possible, and show a little example?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a per-socket struct?  Each buffer struct can have a field that points to the socket struct, no problem, (much as Remy details below).  It's almost inevitable that, as you develop your server, you will end up with more per-socket data than just the socket descriptor, (eg. a record of an incremnting sequence number used to identify buffer order in the handler threads).

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep track of the buffers you pass to `WSARecv()`, etc. You do that by associating an `OVERLAPPED` with each buffer.  When `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` tells you which `OVERLAPPED` is finished, you thus known the associated buffer is ready.

This is commonly handled by defining a `struct` with an `OVERLAPPED` as its first member, so that a pointer to the `OVERLAPPED` is also equal to a pointer to the `struct`.  Then you can put whatever other details you want in the `struct`, like the buffer, socket, etc, whatever your app needs to process the data.

For example:

```c
enum IocpOp { opRead, opWrite };

typedef struct
{
    WSAOVERLAPPED ov;
    IocpOp opCode;
    SOCKET sckt;
    BYTE buffer[256];
    DWORD numBytesInBuffer;
} MYIOCPINFO, *PMYIOCPINFO;

void IoComplete(PMYIOCPINFO io, DWORD errorCode, DWORD numBytesTransferred)
{
    if (errorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // handle failure as needed ...
        free(io);
        return;
    }

    switch (io->opCode)
    {
        case opRead:
            // use io->buffer up to numBytesTransferred as needed ...
            break;

        case opWrite:
            if (numBytesTransferred < io->numBytesInBuffer)
            {
                info->numBytesInBuffer -= numBytesTransferred;
                memmove(io->buffer, io->buffer + numBytesTransferred, io->numBytesInBuffer);

                WSABUF buf;
                buf.len = io->numBytesInBuffer;
                buf.buf = (CHAR*) io->buffer;

                if (WSASend(io->sckt, &buf, 1, NULL, 0, &(io->ov), NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                {
                    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
                    {
                        // handle failure as needed ...
                        free(io);
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            break;
        }

        // reuse io for the next I/O operation on io->sckt
        // or free io now if done using it ...
        free(io);
    }
}

...

PMYIOCPINFO io = malloc(sizeof(MYIOCPINFO));
if (!io) ...
io->opCode = opRead;
io->sckt = sckt;

WSABUF buf;
buf.len = sizeof(io->buffer);
buf.buf = (CHAR*) io->buffer;

DWORD dwFlags = 0;
if (WSARecv(sckt, &buf, 1, NULL, &dwFlags, &(io->ov), NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
        IoComplete(io, WSAGetLastError(), 0);
}

...

PMYIOCPINFO io = malloc(sizeof(MYIOCPINFO));
if (!io) ...
io->opCode = opWrite;
io->sckt = sckt;

// fill io->buffer as needed ...
io->numBytesInBuffer = ...;

WSABUF buf;
buf.len = io->numBytesInBuffer;
buf.buf = (CHAR*) io->buffer;

if (WSASend(sckt, &buf, 1, NULL, 0, &(io->ov), NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
        IoComplete(io, WSAGetLastError(), 0);
}

...

DWORD dwBytesTransferred = 0;
ULONG_PTR ulCompletionKey = 0;
LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped = NULL;

if (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(hIOCP, &dwBytesTransferred, &ulCompletionKey, &lpOverlapped, INFINITE))
{
    if (ulCompletionKey == MySocketIOCPKey) // specified in CreateIOCompletionPort()...
    {
        IoComplete((PMYIOCPINFO)lpOverlapped, ERROR_SUCCESS, dwBytesTransferred);
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}
else
{
    if (lpOverlapped)
    {
        // I/O operation belonging to ulCompletionKey failed...

        if (ulCompletionKey == MySocketIOCPKey) // specified in CreateIOCompletionPort()...
        {
            IoComplete((PMYIOCPINFO)lpOverlapped, GetLastError(), dwBytesTransferred);
        }
        else
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // GetQueuedCompletionStatus() itself failed...
    }
}
```

Comment: not need initialize `info->ov.hEvent` when we bind socket to iocp. so calls `WSACreateEvent` and `WSACloseEvent` can (and must) be dropped. and i think that design error have `sckt` inside `MYIOCPINFO`. really we must have structure per socket and here have (*SOCKET sckt;*) and for every I/O operation - allocate unique `MYIOCPINFO` where must be (referenced) pointer to per socket structure

Comment: may be my bad english. i mean that instead `SOCKET sckt;` have `MY_PER_SOCKET_DATA* pObj;` inside `MYIOCPINFO` and already inside `MY_PER_SOCKET_DATA` have `SOCKET sckt;` also i be create common `void OnIoComplete(PMYIOCPINFO, ULONG dwError);` proc and call it direct after failed I/O operation or after `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` for handle this (like free(info); ) in single place

Comment: *needs to refer to the SOCKET. Whether that is done directly, or via a pointer to something else that holds the SOCKET, is an implementation detail* - yes, agree. simply my opinion that need have 2 separate structs - one per socket and one per I/O

Comment: @RbMm I know what you meant. Whether the `OVERLAPPED` struct refers to the actual `SOCKET` directly, or has a pointer to something else that has the `SOCKET`, is an implementation detail. Either way works. I've done it both ways before.

Comment: yes, my mistake :) `void IoComplete(PMYIOCPINFO io, ULONG errorCode, DWORD dwNumBytes );` more correct and call it as `IoComplete(info, GetLastError(), 0);` or `IoComplete(info, NOERROR, dwNumBytes );`